# How can I reuse an App Script without setting up triggers and auth over and over?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-forms

Update: I'm sorry I didn't post the code originally. In my newbie-ness, I didn't think it honestly mattered, but I've been around long enough to know better. See below:

```
function openForm(e)
{
  populateQuestions();
}

function populateQuestions() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();
  var itemsArray = form.getItems();
  itemsArray.forEach(function(item){
    googleSheetsQuestions[0].forEach(function(header_value, header_index) {
      if(header_value == item.getTitle())
      {
        var choiceArray = [];
        for(j = 1; j < googleSheetsQuestions.length; j++)
        {
          (googleSheetsQuestions[j][header_index] != '') ? choiceArray.push(googleSheetsQuestions[j][header_index]) : null;
        }
        item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choiceArray);
        // If using Dropdown Questions use line below instead of line above.
        //item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choiceArray);
      }
    });     
  });
}

function getQuestionValues() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById('1QeckPxMYSYGMkZ-QggY76u03N1qBKBGL2UEMcUvu7sM');
  var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
  var returnData = questionSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return returnData;
}
```

After months of work, I finally have cracked the script to getting what I wanted. Now I need to use this script over and over in multiple Google Forms (forms, for short). By copy and pasting the Form within Drive, I carry the App Script with each copy, but not the trigger or the authorization needed to run it. I need assistance in learning how I can make this process quicker.

I have very limited knowledge of add-ons and things, but I’m willing to learn. I do not necessarily need this to be a public access Script, just want to make my life less repetitious.

I would also like to make it so after installing the add-on, users can just pick the Sheet/Tab through a UI and not editing the code specifically, but that's a different story.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  We can't help you if you don't show your code and the detail of each step of deployment. Please follow this post : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does the Apps script access any Google Services (apart from Google Form), Like sending an email automatically? or get a File from Google Drive? Depending on this I can recommend a type of trigger that doesn't need to be installed every time. Also, the options that you need to use to deploy the add-on. All that information would be helpful to provide you a proper answer. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @GiselleValladares I'm sorry I didn't post the code originally, I apologize. It's up now. To answer: It pulls the response options from a Google Sheet and when the Form editor is opened/refreshed, it populates the questions that match the Sheet headers with the options. I do not know how to answer the "options that you need to use to deploy the add-on." Any help is appreciated, and again, I apologize for not posting Code originally.

Comment: @WaximCorp I should've known better, I was just a bit square-brain this morning. I've posted the code, but I don't know where to start with deployment at all. I can't answer your "each step" because I have zero clue what to give you.

Comment: I have questions. 1. How are you run your script? For example, your function `openForm` is run by the OnSubmit trigger? 2. About `Now I need to use this script over and over in multiple Google Forms (forms, for short).`, how many Google Forms will you use? 3. Do you want to use your showing script to multiple Google Forms without modifying the script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Right now, it is openForm, and from the Triggers tab on the left when I'm editing the script. "Choose which function to run" is openForm, and "Select Event Type" is On Open. Second question, I'm looking at easily 200. 3. That would be ideal. I'm trying to minimize the amount of manual clicking I have to do at scale, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your situation. But, now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, You can create an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#:%7E:text=for%20a%20simple-,onOpen(),-trigger%2C%20the%20script) so you don't have to add the trigger manually anymore. You should use this:

```
function createFormOpenTrigger() {
  const gf = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('populateQuestions')
      .forForm(gf)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```

Instead of:

```
function openForm(e)
{
  populateQuestions();
}
```

As for the credentials, deploying the script as an add-on I will help you with the OAuth part. However, I was unable to test it today due to propagation. I’m still getting a message that the Apps Script is not bound to the GCP project. I will try my luck tomorrow, in the meantime you can read the following documentation about it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview).

---

Sorry, I took some time to post the answer since you mentioned that you didn't know how to create an add-on, so I tried to add step by step information.

---

**Update:**

You can add this part at the top of the code, this will create a menu that will allow you to run the script for the first time in the Google Form after we make it an Add-on.

```
function onOpen() {
  //you can change the names of the menu, just not change
  // this part "createFormOpenTrigger"
  FormApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('formTest')
    .addItem('Run Apps Script', 'createFormOpenTrigger')
    .addToUi();
}
```

If you do not have a GCP project, you can created one by following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview#create-standard-project), or following the steps:

1. Open the Google API [Console projects list](https://console.developers.google.com/project).
2. Click **Create Project**.
3. Fill out the project information for your add-on.
4. Click **Create**.

Copy the **Project number**, and add it to the Apps Script to [switch to a different standard Cloud project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switch_to_a_different_standard).

1. [image: step 1 add project]
2. [image: step 2 add project]

[Deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/versions#creating_a_version) the Apps Script as an Add-on.

1. [image: step 1 add deploy add-on]
2. [image: step 2 add deploy add-on]
3. [image: step 3 add deploy add-on]

Remember the version number you will need later on. Access to the Google Cloud Project link with the Apps Script.

Setup the [OAuth consent screen](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/configure-oauth-consent-screen), select `internal` to make sure that only you have access to it (and users of your Workspace if you have one)

[image: OAuth consent screen]

We will need to the [Add-on listing](https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish), so we will need to add "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK" in the `Library`.

1. [image: step 1 add library]
2. [image: step 2 add library]
3. [image: step 3 add library]

Add the App configuration information, add all the require information there, the only recommendation I can provide you are these 2:

1. [image: recommendation 1]
2. [image: recommendation 2]

   *Note: this can be found under "Project Settings"*
   [image: Project Settings]

Lastly, fill out the information under "Store listing".

[image: Store listing]

*Note: You can add dummy information if only you are going to use the add-on.*

Once all that is done, use the "App URL" link to install the add-on. When you open a Google Form it will show up under the Add-on list:

[image: add-on list]

And you will see the option to Run the Apps Script, thanks to the last part of the code we added.

[image: run script]

Click on it, and it might ask you for permission the very first time you use it. But it will not request it again even if you add it to a new form.

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly, I really appreciate at least that! Would you mind explaining what you mean by propagation? Is that something I need to do on my end for you to check out? I will try to go through the steps outlined in the link you posted as well. I appreciate your help so far! :)

Comment: No, basically since mine was a brand new code and project, when I tried to publish the add-on for testing I got a message that my project, and the script I created for testing  were not linked. When I had just linked them together. So I will test it out today, to see if I’m allowed to publish the add-on (Internally only).

Comment: @Bysshe, I made it work. I will update the answer soon with the steps.

Comment: I’m going to cry. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Bysshe, I updated the answer. Sorry it took a while to take all the screenshots, and organize them in the answer.

Comment: Do not apologize! I cannot thank you enough. This project has been my main work over the last year and a half, and you’ve just turned it into something I can show other people. Not to be dramatic, but your help will allow me to help a lot of kids and teachers. Like… hundreds each. Thank you so much. Do you have a Ko-fi or something I can at least send you a penance for your help?

Comment: Thank you so much, I just updated my profile with that information.